# 3.2.0 not available on https://downloads.apache.org/spark/

Tags: apache-spark

Why is 3.2.0 not available here any more? https://downloads.apache.org/spark/

Just to be clear, it was here until a few days ago. This link is checked into our internal repo. Realized this artifact is no longer available when the build broke.
Need to make sure we don't go to prod with this version if there is any known major issue with it that caused it to be taken down.

Comment: You can download it from [here](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html)

Comment: "The requested file or directory is not on the mirrors." Do I need to download from an archive to get to 3.2.0? I thought this was the new well publicized version.
https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-3.2.0/spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Download Spark page](https://downloads.apache.org/spark/) has only the latest version of every major version of Spark. If you want a specific version not listed on the main downloads page, you can use [Archived libraries link](https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/).